# mute unmute sound with jQuery on scroll

Tags: jquery, audio, scroll, mute

I want to mute an audio on scrolling and unmute when the scroll is on the top of the page. I have tried many options here but nothing works.

http://codepen.io/chrisgaillard/pen/JbWxWJ

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >1){  
        $('audio').setAttribute('muted'); 
    } else {
        $('audio').setAttribute('unmuted'); 
    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `volume` property, not set the `muted` attribute. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('audio').prop('volume', $(this).scrollTop() > 1 ? 0 : 1);
});
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WopmQx)